# how to show HINDI font correctly by using mpdf library or dompdf in php?

Tags: pdf, fpdf, dompdf, mpdf

First i tried the MPDF but hindi fonts are not working properly. i added and converted utf8 properly. Also connected custom "MANGAL" font still doesn't work in MPDF library
After that i tried with DOMPDF and again same problem with this library.

i attached the code given below please have a look

## DOMPDF CODE

```html
<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf as Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", false);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", false);
define ("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING",false);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER",false);

define("DEBUGCSS",false);
define("DEBUG_LAYOUT",false);
define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_LINES",true);
define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_BLOCKS",true);
define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_INLINE",true); 
define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_PADDINGBOX ",true);

ob_start();


?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css" >
      @font-face {
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
     body {
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
}
        * {
      font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    }
  .wrapper
  {
    border: 1pt solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }


@font-face {
  font-family: "mangal";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(Mangal.ttf) format("truetype");
}
        *{outline: none;box-sizing: border-box;}
        
</style>
<style>
.head{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;


}

.subhead{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2f2f2f;
    border-top: 2px solid #2f2f2f;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 0;

}

.content{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    word-spacing: -.31em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 2% 0 2%;


}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {height:200px;margin:5px;}
table th {height:200px;}
p{padding:4px;}
h2{padding:4px;}
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{ font-family: "mangal", serif;font-size:66px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{ font-family: "mangal", serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-c3ow{border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container m-b-30">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="content" class="col-sm-12 m-b-30">

                <div class="row">
             <div class="head" style="text-align: center;
    position: relative;">
    <div class="headerobjectswrapper">
        <header style="font-size:25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: UPPERCASE;
    clear: both;">TITLE</header>
    </div>

    <div class="subhead">Jabalpur,MP - Tuesday March 3, 2020</div>
</div>
<table class="tg" style="width:100%" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    
    <tbody>
  <tr style="width:1000px">
    <th class="tg-c3ow"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" style="width:270px;height:100px"/></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax" >
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:670px;height:600px"/>
      </td>
    <td colspan="4" class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;"><h2 style="text-align:center; font-size:66px; font-family: "mangal", serif;" lang="hi">
    गौ नर्मदा कुंभ का नर्मदा पूजन व कन्या पूजन के साथ भव्य शुभारम्भ
</h2>
</td>
<td class="tg-0lax" >
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:670px;height:600px"/>
      </td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
    
<td class="tg-0lax" >
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:670px;height:600px"/>
</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">
          <h3  style="background: darkblue;color:#fff;padding: 10px;text-align:center; font-size:66px; font-family:"mangal", serif;">
   <span>आधे घंटे में बिक गये कैदियों द्वारा बनाये गये मास्क जबलपुर मेंान
</span> 
</h3>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" >
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:670px;height:600px"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;margin: 5px;" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><br><p style="margin: 3px; font-family: "mangal", serif;">
       जबलपुर, कलेक्टर भरत यादव की पहल पर केन्द्रीय जेल के बंदियों द्वारा बनाये गये मास्क आज आधा घंटे के भीतर ही हाथों-हाथ बिक गये ।  स्वास्थ्य विभाग की मापदंडों के मुताबिक सूती कपड़े से बनाये गये ये मास्क कलेकटर कार्यालय के मार्गदर्शन कक्ष और कलेकट्रेट भवन में महिला स्व-सहायता समूहों के उत्पादों के प्रदर्शन के लिए स्थापित कृतिका आउटलेट पर विक्रय हेतु रखे गये थे । 

     आम नागरिकों को सात रूपये की दर पर उपलब्ध कराये जा रहे मास्क की बिक्री की शुरूआत कलेक्टर भरत यादव ने की । केन्द्रीय जेल के कैदियों के साथ-साथ वृद्धाश्रम के वृद्धजनों द्वारा तैयार किये गये मास्क भी कलेक्टर कार्यालय के मार्गदर्शन कक्ष में बिक्री हेतु रखे गये थे । संयुक्त संचालक सामाजिक न्याय के मुताबिक नागरिकों को मंगलवार को भी कलेक्टर कार्यालय के मार्गदर्शन कक्ष और कृतिका आउटलेट से सात रूपये की दर पर मास्क उपलब्ध कराये जायेंगे । 

आज से रियायती दर पर छोटे पैक में मिलेंगे हैंड सेनिटाइजर:

     जिला प्रशासन ने आम नागरिकों को कम कीमत पर हैण्ड सेनिटाइजर उपलब्ध कराने की पहल भी की है । हैण्ड सेनिटाइजर मंगलवार से रेडक्रॉस द्वारा संचालित वृद्धाश्रम तथा कलेक्ट्रेट स्थित “कृतिका” आउटलेट एवं कलेक्टर कार्यालय के मार्गदर्शन कक्ष से 30 रूपये की न्यूनतम कीमत पर आम नागरिकों को उपलब्ध कराये जायेंगे । 

     औद्योगिक क्षेत्र रिछाई स्थित हेलाईड केमिकल प्राइवेट लिमिटेड द्वारा निर्मित ये हैण्ड सेनिटाइजर 50 मिली लीटर के पैक में होंगे ।  इन्हें आसानी से पैंट या शर्ट के पॉकेट अथवा पर्स में रखा जा सकेगा । 
        
    </p></td>
    
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;"  colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2> <br>
    <p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "what is happened to me?" he thought. It was not a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
    
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><br>
    <p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/blocks/block_5e5370d6828e8.jpeg" class="img-responsive" style="width:1000px;height:600px"/></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><p><br>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><br><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
    
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;"  colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><br><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
    
    <td class="tg-0lax" style=" font-size:66px;" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><br><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/blocks/block_5e5370d6828e8.jpeg" class="img-responsive" style="width:1070px;height:600px"/></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
   <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/images/image_750x_5ddc877dea79b.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:1070px;height:600px"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/blocks/block_5e5370d6828e8.jpeg"  style="width:870px;height:900px"/></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/images/image_750x_5d790ca6d8c72.jpg"  style="width:870px;height:900px"/></td>
   <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><img src="https://www.think4unitynews.com/newportal2/uploads/images/image_750x_5ddc877dea79b.jpg"  style="width:870px;height:900px"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2"><h2>When darkness overspreads my eyes</h2><p>
        His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. what is happened to me? His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
        
    </p></td>
 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
<td class="tg-0lax" >
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="4">
          <h3 style="background: darkblue;color:#fff;padding: 10px;text-align:center; font-size:66px;">
    इंजीनियर डी राधाकृष्णन जो चेयरमैन त्रिपुरा रेगुलेटरी कमिशन अगरतला का व्याख्यान

</h3>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" >
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/b9/aa/b4b9aa0ca93e9687a1d3b3ae1982cecc.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  </tbody>
</table>

    <div class="head" style="text-align: center;
    position: relative;">
   

  
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></body>
</html>


<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(array('enable_remote' => true));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'DejaVuSans');
//$html1 = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
// $font = $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->get_font("serif", "bold");
// $dompdf->getCanvas()->page_text(72, 18, "                                        Testing", $font, 16, array(0.21,0.11,0.46));
//For view
$dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
// for download
//$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

## MPDF CODE

```html
$html2 = mb_convert_encoding($html1, 'UTF-8', 'cp1252');
        $html3 = utf8_encode($html2);
        
        $html4=iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1',  $html3);
        
        $html=mb_substr($html4, 0, 24090, "UTF-8");
        
        //$html=iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $html2);
        
        
       
        //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
        $pdfFilePath ="download.pdf";
   
   


        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        set_time_limit(600);
        ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
        
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
        
$this->m_pdf->pdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
$this->m_pdf->pdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$this->m_pdf->pdf->autoLangToFont = true;



 // $this->m_pdf->pdf->autoLangToFont = true;
 $this->m_pdf->pdf->fonttrans['freeserif'] = 'dejavusanscondensed';
        //$this->m_pdf->pdf->SetWatermarkText('10 Rupees Only',0.1);
      
      $this->m_pdf->pdf->SetWatermarkText('T4U NEWSPAPER',0.15, '', array(10,40));

      $this->m_pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
      
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
      
      // $this->m_pdf->pdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
        
      $this->m_pdf->pdf->showWatermarkText = true;
      ob_start();
     // $html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        
     
        //download it.
    //   $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");     
     $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output();
```

HTML table is same for both cases.

Server php version is 7+

SCREENSHOT OF PDF
[image]

Please advise me how to show Hindi font correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following font for all the tags

> font-family: freeserif;

It will display your fonts.
I have tested it in mpdf library and it works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
font-family: freeserif;
```

this works greate with mpdf for marathi and hindi language !!!